# Gramática de la frase "las envían acusadas de practicar brujería"

Tags: gramática, pronombres

Contexto: "La mayoría de las mujeres en Ghana, en África Occidental, no tienen voz ni tienen poder. Les tienen miedo. Desde hace diez años el gobierno lucha a contracorriente por cerrar los campos de concentración a donde **las envían acusadas de practicar brujería**."

Entiendo que cuando uno quiere decir "enviar a alguien" y quiere usar pronombres, se usa "le". Pero aquí se usa "las". ¿Alguien me pueda explicar la gramática de este frase? ¿A qué se refiere "las"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El verbo "enviar" es transitivo y, salvo que se use en países donde se practica el "leísmo", lleva los pronombres *la, lo, las, los* como objeto directo:

- Las envían a campos de concentración. (Envían a las mujeres a campos de concentración.)

Sólo lleva *le, les* cuando es ditransitivo, es decir, cuando lleva objeto directo e indirecto, en cuyo caso *le, les* reemplaza al objeto indirecto:

- Les envían flores. (Envían flores a las mujeres.)

Answer (score 0):

Se refiere a las mujeres. En ese contexto, la palabra "las" desempeña el rol de complemento directo. Si se tratara de enviarles alguna cosa a las mujeres, sí se emplearía el complemento indirecto "les", tal y como lo hice en la última frase. Como sabes, este se usa cuando alguien recibe la acción de un verbo o se ve influido por el verbo de alguna forma.

> Le doy el vaso.
>
> Nos robaron la carta.

No obstante, este caso es diferente. En lugar de enviarles algo a las mujeres acusadas de practicar la brujería, a las mujeres las envían a algún lugar. El género gramatical de "mujeres" es femenino y la palabra es plural, de ahi que el complemento directo que le corresponde sea el femenino plural.

Lo que dificulta la comprensión es que la palabra "a" de "a donde" se parece a la "a" que indica el completo indirecto o la "a" que indica un completo directo personificado,  pero en realidad significa el destino de un desplazamiento.  Las envían a algún lugar.